# problems defining a sub range with INDEX formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My understanding is that you can define a range using index.  example I can set a defined name of MyList to

```
 =index(A:A,3,1):index(A:A,5,1)
```

This would be the equivalent of saying A3:A5.  I can then turn around and use index(MyList,1,1) and I would see the contents of A3.  All this works for me.

So I was trying to define a range of sheet names.  I used defined name sheetnames as:

```
 =TRANSPOSE(GET.WORKBOOK(1,Structural!$J$3)&T(NOW()))
```

(I used transpose to get the list vertical)

when I use:

```
 =INDEX(Sheetnames,3,1)
 =INDEX(Sheetnames,6,1)
```

I get the name of my 3rd or 6th sheet in my workbook respectively. So that part is working.  However when I try to define a range like I did for MyList using the following I get #value

```
 =INDEX(INDEX(Sheetnames,3,1):INDEX(Sheetnames,6,1),1,1)
```

QUESTION:

Why is it not working?

As a test to get first sheetname I have also tried:

```
 =OFFSET(Sheetnames,1,1,1,1)
```

This also gave the same error.

What I am ultimately trying to do is generate a pull down list through data validation of all sheet names except the sheets named "Index" and "Master".

Comment: What is `GET.WORKBOOK` in your Excel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Excel's help file on INDEX...

> Reference form
>
> Description
>
> Returns the reference of the cell at the intersection of a particular
>   row and column. If the reference is made up of nonadjacent selections,
>   you can pick the selection to look in.
>
> Syntax
>
> INDEX(reference, row_num, [column_num], [area_num])
>
> The INDEX function syntax has the following arguments.
>
> Reference    Required. A reference to one or more cell ranges
>
> etc...

Therefore, in order to return a reference, you would need to reference a range of cells.  `SheetNames`, however, doesn't refer to a range of cells.  It refers to `GET.WORKBOOK`, which returns an array of values.  In this case, it returns an array of sheet names.

So with the following formula...

```
=INDEX(INDEX(Sheetnames,3,1):INDEX(Sheetnames,6,1),1,1)
```

...it gets evaluated as follows (assuming the workbook is called Book1.xlsx and you have Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, etc)...

```
--> some preliminary evaluations <---

=INDEX("[Book1.xlsx]Sheet3":"[Book1.xlsx]Sheet6",1,1)

=INDEX(#VALUE!,1,1)

=#VALUE!
```

You can evaluate the formula for yourself by selecting the cell containing the formula, and stepping through it using the `Evaluate Formula` button on the Ribbon (Formulas tab > Formula Auditing group).

You can also confirm that `INDEX` doesn't return a reference in this case by using the `ISREF` function.  The following formula should return `FALSE`...

```
=ISREF(INDEX(Sheetnames,3,1))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to run some of that down on my behalf.  I usually forget about the formula evaluate option in excel.  Handy little device at times.  I had not thought to consider using ISREF.  Good pointing that formulat out which I had forgotten.

Comment: wound this be the same reasoning that I cannot use `Sheetnames` for a data validation list?