# Building a dynamic list of select sheetnames

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467779/problems-defining-a-sub-range-with-index-formula)

Ultimate goal is to have a defined name, say "Sheetnames", for use in data validation pick list.  Sheetnames should be a list of all sheet names except for two sheet with the set up information.  Currently they are called "Master Index" and "Progress".  I am trying to avoid using VBA but will resort to it if I must.

**What I have tried**

```
Defined Name "Sheetnames"
=TRANSPOSE(GET.WORKBOOK(1,'Master Index'!$E$4)&T(NOW()))
```

This is apparently a bit of old built in VBA code that dynamically pulls in the list of sheetnames in the workbook.  The transpose converts the horizontal array to vertical and is completely optional.  The now() being a volatile function causes the formula to recalculated anytime a sheet is added, removed, or renamed.

the current output for sheetnames is an array that looks like:

```
[DRAWING LIST work in progress.xlsm]Master Index
[DRAWING LIST work in progress.xlsm]Progress
[DRAWING LIST work in progress.xlsm]Highway
[DRAWING LIST work in progress.xlsm]Structural
[DRAWING LIST work in progress.xlsm]Hydrology
[DRAWING LIST work in progress.xlsm]Electrical
```

I toyed with an array formula (not my strong point) and stripped it down to just the sheet name using:

```
=RIGHT(Sheetnames,LEN(Sheetnames)-LEN(Workbook_Name)-2)
```

Which gave a nice list like so:

```
Master Index
Progress
Highway
Structural
Hydrology
Electrical
```

So I Initially tried to work on the assumption that the first two sheets in the book would be the two that were not used and tried to use INDEX and OFFSET to define the name but failed miserably.

Since there is a possibility that the sheets can be rearranged so that the two in question are not the first two, and that they could be renamed to something else, I used the following to pull the sheet name of the sheets in question.  I repeated the formula once for each sheet.

```
=MID(CELL("address",Progress!A:Z),FIND("]",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z))+1,FIND("'",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z),2)-1-FIND("]",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z)))
```

In the case above I get:

```
Progress
```

Since my idea of using INDEX/OFFSET to define a portion of the SHEETNAMES as a names list blew up in my face, I am having a brain fart and cannot think of how to get the list of sheet names automatically into a defined name for use in Data Validation.

Because I am trying to do it automatically, I am trying to bypass steps where I copy a formula down X number of rows.  Again, if its the only way I will go that route.  Just trying to avoid it.

The list with my example data should look like:

```
Highway
Structural
Hydrology
Electrical
```

**UPDATE:**

Current formula I am working with and not sure where to go with it or on right path is:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(Sheetnames),1))/(RIGHT(Sheetnames,LEN(Sheetnames)-LEN(Workbook_Name)-2)<>MID(CELL("address",Progress!A:Z),FIND("]",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z))+1,FIND("'",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z),2)-1-FIND("]",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z)))),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(Sheetnames)-1,1)))
```

currently I am only testing with excluding the Progress sheet.  Currently this results in 6 which is the largest array entry that contains a name not equaling "Progress"

Basic thought process

AGGREGATE( large or small, ignore errors, generate an index of number and divide by the cases do not equal excluded sheet names, index numbers from 1 to 1** less than the number of sheets in the work book).

**would be increased to 2 when both sheets are excluded.

Instead of getting a result of 6 I was hoping for {1,3,4,5,6}, {6,5,4,3,1}, or some other permutation of those numbers.

I could then turn around and dump into a defined name

```
INDEX(SHEETNAMES,{1,3,4,5,6})
```

and stuck again.

**UPDATE II**

I got it working SORTA

```
 =RIGHT(INDEX(Sheetnames,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(Sheetnames),1))/(RIGHT(Sheetnames,LEN(Sheetnames)-LEN(Workbook_Name)-2)<>MID(CELL("address",Progress!A:Z),FIND("]",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z))+1,FIND("'",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z),2)-1-FIND("]",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z)))),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(Sheetnames)-1,1)))),LEN(INDEX(Sheetnames,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(Sheetnames),1))/(RIGHT(Sheetnames,LEN(Sheetnames)-LEN(Workbook_Name)-2)<>MID(CELL("address",Progress!A:Z),FIND("]",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z))+1,FIND("'",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z),2)-1-FIND("]",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z)))),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(Sheetnames)-1,1)))))-LEN(Workbook_Name)-2)
```

holy ugliness but as a CSE formula it works!  However...  How do you enter a CSE formula in Defined names?

**UPDATE III**

I got it to work in the spreadsheet, but I cannot get it to work in Defined Names

So far what I have working is:

```
Defined Name "Sheetnames" (Characters 56)
=TRANSPOSE(GET.WORKBOOK(1,'Master Index'!$E$4)&T(NOW()))

Defined Name "Workbook_Name" (Characters 41)
=MID(Sheetnames,2,FIND("]",Sheetnames)-2)

Defined Name "Department_Index" (Characters 178)
=AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA(Sheetnames),1))/((Sheetnames<>exclude1)*(Sheetnames<>exclude2)),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA(Sheetnames)-1,1)))

Defined Name "Departments" (Characters 103)
=RIGHT(INDEX(Sheetnames,Department_Index),LEN(INDEX(Sheetnames,Department_Index))-LEN(Workbook_Name)-2)
```

**UPDATE IV**

I did not realize that I had a formula sitting in E4.  I have now defined the formula in E4 as:

```
Defined Name "wbFilename"
=MID(CELL("filename",PROJ_NAME),FIND("[",CELL("filename",PROJ_NAME))+1,FIND("]",CELL("filename",PROJ_NAME))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",PROJ_NAME))-1)

Defined Name "PROJ_NAME"
='Master Index'!$B$1
```

and the update "Sheetnames" is now:

```
Defined Name "Sheetnames"
=TRANSPOSE(GET.WORKBOOK(1,wbFilename)&T(NOW()))
```

and now I am stuck as I cannot get it working in with data validation

Comment: If the sheets can be renamed or moved, how does Excel know which sheets to exclude from the list?  Is there a cell somewhere on the sheets that should be included that as "Include" or "X" or something in them to let Excel know? Without that, I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: @tigeravatar yes, this formula points to a cell on the sheet that is to be excluded and pulls its name: =MID(CELL("address",Progress!A:Z),FIND("]",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z))+1,FIND("'",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z),2)-1-FIND("]",CELL("address",Progress!A:Z)))   So I repeat this twice to hard code a location on each of the sheets to be excluded.

Comment: wow, why all this head-ache? Use VBA, you already have it enabled...

Comment: @A.S.H Because I am extremely weak in VBA.  if I could remember my turbo pascal and I could actually use that in EXCEL sure!  And as I stated somewhere I will use VBA, but was hoping for a formula solution.

Comment: I understand. But the way I see it, you should definitely cut it short and go for the VBA solution. Not only will it be easier and straightforward, but it avoids you ending up with a mess of complex formulas that are hard to maintain, modify, evolve, etc.